# Runtime library search order on AIX

Tags: aix, shared-library, dynamic-linking, linker

If I understand correctly, the variables `LIBPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` have a higher priority than the argument to the linker `-blibpath`. I'm looking for how to tell the loader to search for libraries along the paths prescribed during compilation (that is, `-blibpath` or some other). On linux, for example, there is `-rpath`, which has priority higher than variables. I'm looking for an analog on AIX.

I'm also looking for where the priority of paths for finding libraries on AIX is clearly described.

Comment: I don't know about "priorities", but with option `-bipath` you can store the full path of the shared object. Details here: https://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond thank, it works, but only when the compilation takes place directly on the AIX computer. When I try to cross-compile the code (from linux to AIX), it turns out that cross-compiler does not have the -bipath flag

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond ./powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0-gcc --version
powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0-gcc (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: It is `-Wl,-bipath` when `ld` is invoked from `gcc`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0-gcc -Wl,-bipath /tmp/libgcc_s.a main.c 
/opt/crossaix/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.8.3/../../../../powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/bin/ld: target ipath not found
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Indeed, the Gnu linker is not compatible with Aix-linker.